# How to create grails project only for domain classes?

Tags: grails

I'm starting to create a new project and I need to have a separate project only for the domains, which will be packed into a jar file to be used on another files.
I'm wondering the best way to do that with Grails.
Is there a way to create a grails project only with the domain classes?

Answer (score 0):

Without more info (grails version especially!), it's hard to say for sure but you could certainly put all of your domain classes in a plugin.  If you're using Grails 3+, plugins are released as jar files anyway, so that might work pretty well for you too.

`grails create-plugin (your plugin name)`

And then just use your plugin in your build.gradle, like any other plugin.  It's a bit different in grails 2, but the documentation could help you out there too.

Comment: I think that will work for me. Thank you! Where can I find all the kind of project I can create with grails? Like this "create-plugin"?

Comment: http://docs.grails.org/latest/ and then go to "command line" section in the quick reference on the right side.  The docs aren't always 100% correct (they're a work in progress, just like the framework!) but overall they're very helpful!